# spplot R and order of panels for Lattice plots

Tags: r, sp

I have a shapefile with various attributes. I want to plot the shapefile using `spplot'.

I first read the shapefile

```
A <- readOGR('myshapefile.shp')
```

I am using the following command:

```
p <- spplot(A, c('lulc', 'lulc_2', 'lulc_3', 
                 'lulc_4', 'lulc_5', 'lulc_6', 'lulc_7'), 
            col.regions=myColors, 
            col='transparent', 
            names.attr = c(1998, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2009, 2014, 2017))
```

Surprisingly, the map order is from bottom to top and left to right in 3 rows.

I want them to appear from top to bottom and left to right order i.e. 1998 should appear first and 2017 should appear last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `as.table=TRUE`:

> ‘as.table’ logical; start drawing panels upper-left instead of
>         lower-left

See also `?xyplot`

> ‘as.table’: A logical flag that controls the order in which
>               panels should be displayed: if ‘FALSE’ (the default),
>               panels are drawn left to right, bottom to top (as in a
>               graph); if ‘TRUE’, left to right, top to bottom (as in a
>               table).